# Масштаб страницы

Tags: javascript

Можно ли узнать текущий масштаб страницы ?

Comment: `Math.round(window.devicePixelRatio * 100)`

Comment: @Deonis думаю стоит опубликовать ответ, но уже с разъяснением.

Comment: @ΝNL993, пардон, но нет времени. Я думаю, что вы легко справитесь )

Comment: @Deonis готово :) Ещё добавил способ для IE7+

Answer (score 1):

Текущий масштаб страницы можно узнать с помощью `devicePixelRatio`. Вот так:

```js
function getPageScale() {
  return Math.round(window.devicePixelRatio * 100)
}

let pageScale = getPageScale()

console.log(pageScale)
```

Если вы хотите узнать точное значение, просто уберите `Math.round` и его скобки соответственно. Сам `devicePixelRatio`, если исходить [из MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio), `devicePixelRatio` является соотношением разрешения дисплея текущего устройства в физических пикселях к разрешению в логических (CSS) пикселях. Если немного порыскать в интернете, то можно себе сделать вот такой вот способ для IE7+:

```js
console.log(getPageScale())

function getPageScale() {
  if(window.devicePixelRatio) {
    return roundify(window.devicePixelRatio)
  }

  return getPageScaleIE()
}

function getPageScaleIE() {
  if (window.screen.systemXDPI === void 0) {
    return getPageScaleIE7()
  }

  return roundify(window.screen.deviceXDPI / window.screen.logicalXDPI)
}

function getPageScaleIE7() {
  var node = document.body

  if(node.getBoundingClientRect) {
    var rect = node.getBoundingClientRect()
    var physicalWidth = rect.right - rect.left
    var logicalWidth = node.offsetWidth

    return roundify(physicalWidth / logicalWidth)
  }

  return 100
}

function roundify() {
  return Math.round(arguments[0] * 100)
}
```

Источники:

- [deviceXDPI property (screen)](http://help.dottoro.com/ljuxiphf.php)
- [Window.devicePixelRatio](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio#%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB)

Answer (score 0):

Скорее так:

```js
console.log(outerWidth / innerWidth * 100)
```

А `devicePixelRatio`, это экран.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).